# Powershell+Selenium. Find element by id contains

Tags: powershell, selenium

I have a website that has an element with ID "news-id-01" . I am doing FindElementByID("news-id-01") and I get the desired result.

But instead of the 01 numbers on different pages there are different figures. How do I make it so that I can search for IDs that contain the text "news-id"?

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below to match element that **contains** `"news-id"` in `id` attribute

```
FindElementByXPath("//*[contains(@id, 'news-id')]")
```